# how to use yield dynamically that doesnt effect the whole environment

Tags: python, schedule, simpy

I am new to python and I want to ask something in detail about simpy environment. so let's say it like this I have **2 cars** and each car has to perform **same function at different time** but the problem is, when I used ***yield env.timeout(something)*** it change the **whole environment time** but in actual **I want to do it separately**. For example if **car A** is moving from **point 1**  at time **t1** and doing some work at **time t2** and after that the **car 2**  is moving and doing samework at **time t3** and **t4** but I want to do this like, let say the **car A** is moving from point 1 at **time t1** and **doing somework at time t2** in the same case the I want to move **car 2** at **time t1.5** even the **car 1** is on its way at **time t1.5**. both of them should not be in depending mood.
How to synchronize that?
If someone has experience please help.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define Car A and Car B as two difference environment process.  Do not put CarA and  CarB in the same function

```
env.process(CarA(env))
env.process(CarB(env))
```